# How to stop Canvas from affecting Grid size in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In the code below, surrounding the Grid with a Canvas limits the Grid size. This behavior however does not take place in WPF.

```
    <Canvas Background="AliceBlue">
    <Grid BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="50" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!--<Button  Content="Button"  />-->
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: Child Elements in Canvas will not fill the whole canvas. They will take the default Width and Height of themselves.

Comment: @AVKNaidu, in case, how do you suggest overcoming this issue? In other words, how to make the Grid fill the entire Canvas space

Comment: Depends, If you have a plan to stack items on top of each other with relative position on canvas, To fill it, you need to bind the width and height of Grid to Canvas Actual Width and Height. If that is not what you want, Remove the canvas completely.

Comment: @AVKNaidu Right, adding  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TheCanvas}"  and Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TheCanvas}" to the Grid control fixed the issue. You could add it as an answer if you would like to.

Comment: I would prefer you post this as an answer to the question. I just gave the idea for you to work on. Your comment was the actual answer.

Comment: First, what's the reason of using a `Canvas` here? Second, this behavior should be the same in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AVKNaidu suggested, "To fill it, you need to bind the width and height of Grid to Canvas Actual Width and Height."

**Working Code**:

```
<Canvas Background="AliceBlue" x:Name="TheCanvas">
    <Grid BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="50" 
          Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TheCanvas}" 
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=TheCanvas}">
         ...........
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```